# Express sequence as a function

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions

[image]

I've been trying to solve this practice problem. I'm having problems with (a) and (b). I did (b) first, finding out generating functions for B(x), C(x) and D(x). I got the following:

B(x) = 1/(1-x)

C(x) = (1-x^3)/(1-x)^2

D(x) = x/(1-x)^2

However, I don't know how to express these as functions of bn, cn, and dn in part (a) of the problem. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint for (a)**

$$a_0=2=1+1+2×0=$$
$$b_0+c_0+2d_0$$
and
$$a_2=4=1+1+2×1=$$
$$b_1+c_1+2d_1$$

for $n>1,$
$$a_n=1+2n=1+0+2×n=$$
$$b_n+c_n+2d_n $$

which is also true for $n=0,1$.

Comment: Thanks! One more question, for B(x), would the generating function be C(x) = (1-x^3)/(1-x)^2 or C(x) = (1-x^2)/(1-x)^2?

Comment: How is defined the generating function.